# Force simulation is jittery when using svg transforms to update position

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg, d3-force-directed

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/e665h15j/)

I've noticed that when updating positions of svg elements in a [d3-force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) diagram, updating the positions of elements using (in the case of circles) the `cx` and `cy` attributes is much smoother than using the `transform` attribute.

In the example JSFiddle, there are two separate force simulations side-by-side. The one on the left updates positions using the `transform` attribute:

```
sim_transform.on('tick', function () {
  circles_transform.attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });
});
```

The one on the right updates positions using the `cx` and `cy` attributes of a circle:

```
sim_position.on('tick', function () {
  circles_position
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
});
```

The simulations appear identical until they're just about to become static, at which point the one using transforms starts to jitter quite a bit. Any ideas what is causing this? Can it be fixed so that the animation remains smooth using transforms?

Comment: Wow, that is something! I was just about to write that this was nonsense, because I was not able to reproduce it in Chrome and IE, but then I tried it in Firefox where it became visible immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue you're observing (only reproducible in FireFox, as [@altocumulus noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278808/force-simulation-is-jittery-when-using-svg-transforms-to-update-position-rather#comment87579609_50278808)) has something to do with the way FF uses floating numbers for the `translate` of the `transform` attribute.

We can see this if we set both simulations to use integers, doing `~~(d.x)`  and `~~(d.y)`. Have a look, both will jitter:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var graph_transform = gen_data();
var graph_position = gen_data();

var force_left = d3.forceCenter(
  parseInt(svg.style('width')) / 3,
  parseInt(svg.style('height')) / 2
)
var force_right = d3.forceCenter(
  2 * parseInt(svg.style('width')) / 3,
  parseInt(svg.style('height')) / 2
)

var sim_transform = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('left', force_left)
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(65))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(id));
var sim_position = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('right', force_right)
  .force('collide', d3.forceCollide(65))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(id));

var g_transform = svg.append('g');
var g_position = svg.append('g');

var circles_transform = g_transform.selectAll('circle')
  .data(graph_transform.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 40);

var circles_position = g_position.selectAll('circle')
  .data(graph_position.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 40);

sim_transform
  .nodes(graph_transform.nodes)
  .force('link')
  .links(graph_transform.links);

sim_position
  .nodes(graph_position.nodes)
  .force('link')
  .links(graph_position.links);

sim_transform.on('tick', function() {
  circles_transform.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + (~~(d.x)) + ',' + (~~(d.y)) + ')';
  });
});

sim_position.on('tick', function() {
  circles_position
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return ~~d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return ~~d.y;
    })
});

function id(d) {
  return d.id;
}

function gen_data() {
  var nodes = [{
      id: 'a'
    },
    {
      id: 'b'
    },
    {
      id: 'c'
    },
    {
      id: 'd'
    }
  ]

  var links = [{
      source: 'a',
      target: 'b'
    },
    {
      source: 'b',
      target: 'c'
    },
    {
      source: 'c',
      target: 'd'
    },
    {
      source: 'd',
      target: 'a'
    }
  ];
  return {
    nodes: nodes,
    links: links
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

So, in your original code, it seems like the circles move correctly when using `cx` and `cy`, but they jump from integer to integer when using `translate` (or maybe half pixel, see the last demo). If the hypothesis here is correct, the reason that you just see the effect when the simulation is cooling down is because, at that moment, the movements are smaller.

**Demos**

Now, if we get rid of the simulation, we can see that this strange behaviour also happens with a very basic `transform`. To check this, I created a transition for a big black circle, using a linear ease and a very long time (to facilitate seeing the issue). The circle will move 30px to the right. I also put a gridline to make the *jumps* more noticeable.

(Warning: the demos below are only reproducible in **FireFox**, you won't see any difference in Chrome/Safari)

If we use `cx`, the transition is smooth:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gridlines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", 200)
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .style("stroke", "lightgray")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 98)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr("cx", "230")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

However, if we use `translate`, you can see the circle jumping 1px at every move:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gridlines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", 200)
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .style("stroke", "lightgray")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 98)
  .transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

For you people running this in Chrome/Safari, this is how the last snippet looks like in Firefox. It's like the circle is being moved half a pixel at every change... definitely not as smooth as changing `cx`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gridlines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", 200)
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return 300 + d * 3
  })
  .style("stroke", "lightgray")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 98);
  
var timer = d3.timer(function(t){
  if(t>10000) timer.stop();
  circle.attr("cx", 200 + (~~(60/(10000/t))/2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

As this is an implementation issue only visible in FF, it may be worth reporting a bug.

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work on this, [bug has been reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460863).